# Returning a named tuple from a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have been trying all day and have had many attempts but not luck. I have the following Linq query that returns results.

This query returns IEnumerable<sketchEntity>:

```
var temp = from entity in remainingEntities
            where entity.EndPoint.FuzzyEqual(matchPoint, _tolerance)
            select entity;
```

This query returns (IEnumerable<sketchEntity>, end)

```
var temp = (from entity in remainingEntities
            where entity.EndPoint.FuzzyEqual(matchPoint, _tolerance)
            select entity, ChainMatchType.End);
```

Neither of these is what I want. Each result in the final IEnumerable needs to be a named tuple with each tuple having a ISketchEntity and ChainMatchType:

```
List<(ISketchEntity sketchEntityName, ChainMatchType MatchName)>
```

I will be doing similar queries three different times.

1. When certain types of ISketchEntities match an EndPoint.
2. When certain types of ISketchEntities match a StartPoint.
3. When certain types of ISketchEntities match a CenterPoint.

When I run each query I want to add the type of result using the Enum to denote the type of match.

```
public enum ChainMatchType
{
    Start,
    End,
    Center
}
```

My plan is to combine all three queries into one result before returning the result.

How can I format my LINQ to get the result into a named tuple:

```
Name            DataType
entity:         ISketchEntity
MatchType:      ChainMatchType
```

**EDIT**
FuzzyEquals is a custom extension. It compares two points using a +/- tolerance. I am working with CAD data and past history tells me that sometimes two points can be close enough to be equal but don't have exactly the same coordinates.

```
    public static bool FuzzyEqual(this ISketchPoint sp, ISketchPoint other, double tolerance)
    {
        if (
            sp.X > other.X - tolerance && sp.X < other.X + tolerance &&
            sp.Y > other.Y - tolerance && sp.Y < other.Y + tolerance &&
            sp.Z > other.Z - tolerance && sp.Z < other.Z + tolerance
        )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

After seeing it just now I guess it could be simplified to:

```
    public static bool FuzzyEqual(this ISketchPoint sp, ISketchPoint other, double tolerance)
    {
        return sp.X > other.X - tolerance && sp.X < other.X + tolerance &&
               sp.Y > other.Y - tolerance && sp.Y < other.Y + tolerance &&
               sp.Z > other.Z - tolerance && sp.Z < other.Z + tolerance;
    }
```

Comment: Is this Linq-to-Entities (i.e. Entity Framework), or Linq-to-Objects?

Comment: Where and how is `FuzzyEqual` defined, out of curiosity?

Comment: Did you try to return a new tuple for exmple: Tuple.Create(sketchEntityName: entity, MatchName: ChainMatchType.End)

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi That's `System.Tuple` which is not the same as `ValueTuple`.

Comment: @Dai right, that part seems exessive

Comment: @Dai - Please see the edit above about FuzzyEqual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I recommend using Linq with only extension-methods, and avoid the keyword-style `from`, `in`, `where`, `select`.

  - I'll admit this *is* a personal preference of mine - but C#'s Linq keyword feature is somewhat aneamic and you *almost always* end-up needing to use some extension-methods (especially `ToList` and `Include`) and mixing keyword and extension-method styles makes things harder to read.
- Anyway, you just need to add the value-tuple in a `Select` step, which can be a method parameter (though you cannot *easily* parameterize value-tuple member names - it's possible, but out-of-scope for this question).

Like so:

```
List<( ISketchEntity sketchEntityName, ChainMatchType matchName )> withName = remainingEntities
    .Where( e => e.EndPoint.FuzzyEqual( matchPoint, _tolerance ) )
    .Select( e => ( sketchEntityName: e, matchName: matchName ) )
    .ToList()
```

As a parameterized method:

(I don't know what `matchPoint` and `_tolerance` are btw).

```
public static List<( ISketchEntity sketchEntityName, ChainMatchType matchName )> Get2( this IEnumerable<ISketchEntity> entities, ChainMatchType matchType )
{
    // Precondition:
    if( entities is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entities));

    return entities 
        .Where( e => e.EndPoint.FuzzyEqual( matchPoint, _tolerance ) )
        .Select( e => ( sketchEntityName: e, matchName: matchType ) )
        .ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need braces around the select part:

```
var temp = (from entity in remainingEntities
            where entity.EndPoint.FuzzyEqual(matchPoint, _tolerance)
            select (entity, ChainMatchType.End));
```

Comment: this requires you to have executed the query inb4 doing the from query, i suggest using `Tuple<T1,T2>(v1,v2).ToValueTuple()` instead as it executes on iqueryable